# SharePoint checkout File by python

Tags: python, rest, post, sharepoint

So, I already searched a lot in different forums but I just can´t make it work for me.

I want to automate a tool. Therefore I´m trying to checkout a SharePoint File in a python script:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36', 'X-RequestDigest': 'form digest value'}
url = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/team/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/team/Shared Documents/project/doc.xlsb')/checkout()"

response = requests.post(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(USERNAME, PASSWORD),headers=headers)
```

I´m getting the response "403 Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource." I can CheckOut the file manually so I clearly have the rights to do it. Is there a problem with the authentification or are there other solutions?

Comment: Your url suggests that the server is an API (contains "_api").
If it's the case Is there any documentation provided with the API ? Especially a chapter about authentication.
When you say you checked out the file manually, do you mean with a curl command ? with a browser ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems that you are not passing the correct form digest value in your headers. The form digest value is a security token that SharePoint requires for any POST requests that modify the state of the server. You can obtain the form digest value by making a POST request to the /_api/contextinfo endpoint and extracting the value from the response. For example:

import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

## Get the form digest value

digest_url = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/team/_api/contextinfo"
digest_response = requests.post(digest_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(USERNAME, PASSWORD))
digest_value = digest_response.json()['d']['GetContextWebInformation']['FormDigestValue']

## Use the form digest value in the headers

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36', 'X-RequestDigest': digest_value}
url = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/team/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/team/Shared Documents/project/doc.xlsb')/checkout()"

response = requests.post(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(USERNAME, PASSWORD),headers=headers)

## Check the status code

```
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("File checked out successfully")
else:
    print("Error: ", response.status_code, response.reason)
```

Explanation:

The form digest value is a way for SharePoint to prevent cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attacks, where a malicious site can send requests to SharePoint on behalf of a user without their consent. The form digest value is a random string that is generated by SharePoint and stored in a hidden input field in the page. When a user submits a form or makes a POST request, SharePoint validates that the form digest value matches the one stored in the server. If they don't match, the request is rejected.

When you are using requests to make POST requests to SharePoint, you need to obtain the form digest value from the /_api/contextinfo endpoint, which returns a JSON object with the form digest value and other information. You need to pass this value in the X-RequestDigest header of your subsequent requests, so that SharePoint can verify that you are authorized to perform the action.

Examples:

Here are some examples of how to use requests to make POST requests to SharePoint with the form digest value:

- To create a new folder in a document library:

```py
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

# Get the form digest value
digest_url = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/team/_api/contextinfo"
digest_response = requests.post(digest_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(USERNAME, PASSWORD))
digest_value = digest_response.json()['d']['GetContextWebInformation']['FormDigestValue']

# Use the form digest value in the headers
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36', 'X-RequestDigest': digest_value, 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose', 'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'}

# Specify the folder name and the parent folder path
folder_name = "New Folder"
parent_folder = "/sites/team/Shared Documents/project"

# Construct the payload
payload = {
    '__metadata': {'type': 'SP.Folder'},
    'ServerRelativeUrl': parent_folder + '/' + folder_name
}

# Construct the url
url = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/team/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/folders?@target='https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/team'"

# Make the POST request
response = requests.post(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(USERNAME, PASSWORD),headers=headers, json=payload)

# Check the status code
if response.status_code == 201:
    print("Folder created successfully")
else:
    print("Error: ", response.status_code, response.reason)
```

- To upload a file to a document library:

```py
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

# Get the form digest value
digest_url = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/team/_api/contextinfo"
digest_response = requests.post(digest_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(USERNAME, PASSWORD))
digest_value = digest_response.json()['d']['GetContextWebInformation']['FormDigestValue']

# Use the form digest value in the headers
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36', 'X-RequestDigest': digest_value, 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose', 'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'}

# Specify the file name and the file content
file_name = "test.txt"
file_content = b"Hello world"

# Specify the folder path
folder_path = "/sites/team/Shared Documents/project"

# Construct the url
url = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/team/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + folder_path + "')/Files/add(url='" + file_name + "',overwrite=true)?@target='https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/team'"

# Make the POST request
response = requests.post(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(USERNAME, PASSWORD),headers=headers, data=file_content)

# Check the status code
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("File uploaded successfully")
else:
    print("Error: ", response.status_code, response.reason)
```

Answer (score -1):

it looks like you're trying to connect to a corporate account. 
This probably does not answer your question, but here I might suggest another way using the Microsoft Graph API.

The advantage of this way is that every user can use this interface with his individual rights. To allow authentication you first need to register your application at Azure APP (https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade).

To connect via Python you can use the o365 module (https://pypi.org/project/O365/). This allows you to communicate with sharepoint via this interface. Here you will also find further explanations to connect to Sharepoint.

Comment: Actually thanks for that answer anyway. It took me a bit to set it all up but it´s a great tool. Unfortunately the SharePoint interface isn´t documated yet and looking into the sharepoint.py file, I find nothing about checking out a file. But I´ll try to make it work as more or less I got no other choice.